# beats / libbeats kafka output only works without compression

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-kafka, filebeat

I'm sending log messages to Kafka with Filebeat (current version: RC1).

Everything works with

```
compression: "none"
```

If I try to set the compression to "gzip" or "snappy" there are no errors but also no messages in the topic.

I also tried to send messages with the Kafka console producer script for different compressions (gzip, snappy, lz4) - this works.

Answer (score 0):

I'have found the issue: https://github.com/elastic/beats/issues/2651

Current workaround: comment "version" in config

```
#version: 0.10.0.0
```